# Particularly Tricky Recurrence Relation (Master's Theorem)

Tags: recursion

Master's theorem is shown below,

[image]

The recursive function to be solved is shown below,

[image]

I understand that `a` refers to the number of recursive calls in this function (**3** in this case). `b` refers to what the input size is being divided by in each recursive call. Which I believe should be **4**.
`d` refers to the overhead of each recursive call, which should be 1.

So we have:

```
a = 3
b = 4...?
d = 1
```

The problem is, b apparently doesn't equal 4.

Now the actual answer shows that the answer is:

[image]

Which seems incorrect, since given the Master's Theorem, I don't see how `n` is being subtracted by a constant.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since n refers to "the length in bits of x", you should translate n with the binary log of x, and (n-2) with the binary log of x/4.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Great! Can't believe I missed that!