# Master Theorem: How to find the value of b in this recurrence relation

Tags: recurrence-relation, master-theorem

The master theorem is used with recurrences of the form `T(n) = aT(n/b) + f(n)` where a >=1 and b > 1, in which case the value of b can be easily seen from the recurrence, however I have a recurrence of the form

```
T(n) = T((n/4)+3) + f(n)
```

How do I get the value of b in this case?

This question [Particularly Tricky Recurrence Relation (Master's Theorem)](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/11635/particularly-tricky-recurrence-relation-masters-theorem) is the only thing I found that has a similar case with T(n/4 +1) but gives no detail about how the b was calculated.

Comment: See [our reference question](/questions/2789/solving-or-approximating-recurrence-relations-for-sequences-of-numbers) for other methods you can apply.

Comment: You can also investigate how `T` and $T'$ given by $T'(n) = T'(n/4) + f(n)$ differ.

Comment: Welcome to Computer Science! Note that you can use LaTeX here to typeset mathematics in a more readable way. See [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/q/271/) for a short introduction.

Answer (score 3):

You can't use the Master theorem on that function $T$.

However, as Raphael suggests, you *could* consider the related function

$$T'(n) = T'(n/4) + f(n),$$

use the Master theorem to find a solution for $T'$, and then *check* whether that's a valid solution for $T$ too.  No guarantees that it will be, but you could check.

In other words, you could use the *guess-and-check* strategy to solve the recurrence for $T$, where your "guess" comes from solving $T'$ using the Master theorem.  See also [Solving or approximating recurrence relations for sequences of numbers](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/2789/755) for an explanation of *guess-and-check* (also called *guess-and-prove*).

One caveat is that guess-and-check will probably require an explicit solution to $T$, with specific constants.  In other words, it's usually not enough to guess that $T(n) = O(g(n))$; you will typically need to guess a specific constant $c$ such that $T(n) \le c \cdot  g(n)$, one that will enable the proof to go through.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can use master's theorem. However, there is a much more general version of that called [Akra-Bazzi Method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Akra%E2%80%93Bazzi_method) which can be used to solve this problem

Comment: This question [link](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/11635/particularly-tricky-recurrence-relation-masters-theorem) has T(x/4+1) and looks like the master theorem was used but no details were given. So I suspect that it indeed might be used in this case. I would love to ask how they got b in that post but I don't have enough reputation to comment on that post so I was hoping someone here knows how. I edited my question to make it clear that I am specifically interested in how to use the master theorem.

Comment: @EvaD No, it doesn't. There is `f(x/4 - 1)` but that's in the algorithm, not in the running-time recurrence. Is that the mistake you are making?

Comment: @EvaD, that question was a bit sloppy; the Master theorem doesn't seem to apply to that question (they might have used it, but strictly speaking, its use doesn't seem to be justified).  So I think iLoveCamelCase's answer is the one that is ultimately correct.

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is to use the master theorem to get lower and upper bounds separately, and then try to use other methods to prove a tight bound.

So, on one hand we have

$T(n) \leq T(n/3) + f(n)$

this is true because $T$ is an increasing function and $n/4 + 3 \leq n/3$ for $n$ big enough.

You will be using the master theorem with the following recurrence:

$T'(n) = T'(n/3) + f(n)$

and getting $T'(n) \in \Theta(g(n))$ for some $g$. So you will conclude $T(n) \in O(g(n))$

For the lower bound use $T(n) \geq T(n/4) + f(n)$.